# "This semester" or "In this semester"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Is there any rule or a governing principle telling when the preposition "in" must be used before a specified period of time?

> **This semester**, he has finally abandoned his habit of reading comic
>   books in class.

or

> **In this semester**, he has finally abandoned his habit of reading comic
>   books in class.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76154/discussion-on-question-by-brilliant-this-semester-or-in-this-semester).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"This semester, he has finally abandoned his habit of reading comic books in class.

is natural sounding in English.

"In this semester, he has finally abandoned his habit of reading comic books in class." is not natural sounding.

**There is no need for a prepositional phrase. You can see that my putting the phrase at the end**:

**He has finally abandoned his habit of reading comic books in class this semester**.

The comma signals that the phrase can be moved.

You abandon your habit (abandon=give up) of doing something this year, this week, today, this month. No prepositions are needed.

To abandon or give up something thing + time

You don't give up or abandon something "in the semester".

You abandon or give up something this semester.

Comment: So, is it unidiomatic to use the prepositional phrase, "In this semester", or you just feel more convenience with less words?

Comment: No, it is not unidiomatic to use the phrase or say "in this semester". It is awkward to use it in utterances of the kind I have given. If you understand how the verbs abandon and give up work. If you put it at the end of the sentence (where it "comes" from in fact), you will see that in is not needed. To give up some thing today, yesterday, this year etc.

Comment: Yeah, I see your points.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that *in this semester* implies that the item(s) is/are of minor importance, and *this semester* implies the item(s) is/are of major importance. I would usually use *this semester* without *in*.

In your examples I think the second one implies his "achievement" is minor, i.e. he hasn't really done much, while the first one suggests abandoning comics in class was a good achievement, hopefully not his only one.

Comment: In this week, I am driving to school. In this semester makes the sentence agrammatical.

Comment: @Mike B Can you explain why you think the inclusion of **in** downgrades the importance of any achievement?

Comment: @Ronald Sole I don't have a formal explanation, but the feeling I get is that "in" means the item is fully contained inside the time period. Compare to "in" as a preposition of place, which implies there are  other bits in the same space, e.g. in the cupboard, in the garden, and I get the same feeling about "in this semester."